# ExternalInterface API in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, mxml, mxmlc

How to resolve the following error in the  mxml program?

The error is

```
       Loading configuration file /opt/flex/frameworks/flex-config.xml
       /home/tom-j/programs/flex/html/aa.mxml(17):  Error: Access of undefined property addBody.

       ExternalInterface.addCallback("addBody", addBody);
```

`Program is`

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">

     <mx:Script>
     <![CDATA[

     import mx.controls.Button;
     import mx.controls.Alert;
     import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
     import flash.display.Sprite;
     import flash.media.*;
     import flash.net.*;
     import flash.external.*;
     import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

     //                "javascript function", flash function
     ExternalInterface.addCallback("addBody", addBody);

     public function addBody():void
     {
       Alert.show("Got input from JS");
     }
         ]]>                
     </mx:Script>
     </mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try putting this call into an onCreationComplete event handler:

```
protected function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    //just in case to prevent security exceptions:
    Security.allowDomain("*.yourdomain.com");
    Security.allowDomain("localhost");
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("addBody", addBody);
}
```

The raised error could be because when processing the `addCallback` line, there did not exist the `addBody` method.

**Update** calling the `addBody` method from javascript

in your html you must have the swf embedded ~like this:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="your_flash_app" width="1000" height="520"
    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
    <param name="movie" value="YourFlashApp.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#bee3f6" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <embed src="YourFlashApp.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#bee3f6" width="1000" height="520" name="your_flash_app" align="middle" play="true" loop="false"
        quality="high" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
    </embed>
</object>
```

To call the `addBody` method from javascript, first you must locate the flash application there:

```
//this only works for sure in IE browsers, but there are workarounds 
//to deal with the others.
var flashApp = document.getElementById("your_flash_app");
flashApp.addBody();
```

Comment: How to call the addBody from js now..?

Comment: check my update for the sample. note, that afaik `document.getElementById` will return the object you need only in ie browsers (at least this was the situation 2-3 years ago). if you need, i can share my js workaround for the other browsers too

Comment: I have posted the full code on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675870/javascript-error-on-calling-flex-as-function Can u please have alook at it..