# Javascript error on calling flex-AS function

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, flash, mxml

I am trying to call call action script function from JS but i get the following error

```
   Error: getFlashMovie(swfobjectID).sayWhat is not a function
```

Can any body let me know what am i doing wrong here

```
     <html>

     <OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="myMovieName" WIDTH="225" HEIGHT="200">
     <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="ax.swf" /> <PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high" /> <PARAM NAME="bgcolor" VALUE="#FFFFFF" /> <EMBED href="ax.swf" src="ax.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF NAME="myMovieName" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"> </EMBED> </OBJECT>



     <script>
     function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
        alert("In get Flash Movie");
         document.getElementById(movieName).setAttribute("name", movieName);
         var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
         return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
     }

     function sayWhat()
     {
        alert("In call as");
        var swfobjectID = 'myMovieName';  
        alert(swfobjectID);
        //call flex function 
        getFlashMovie(swfobjectID).sayWhat();
     }
     </script>
     <input type="button" onclick="javascript:sayWhat();" value="Click Me" />

     </html>
```

`MXML`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" creationComplete="initCamera()">

  <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

  import mx.controls.Button;
  import mx.controls.Alert;
  import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.media.*;
  import flash.net.*;
  import flash.external.*;
  import flash.external.ExternalInterface;



  public function sayWhat():void {
  Alert.show("Hi");
  }

  public function initCamera():void {
  //stop();
  ExternalInterface.addCallback("sayWhat", sayWhat);

  }        


   ]]>               
  </mx:Script>
  </mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working sample application that calls your flex sayWhat funciton from javascript.

It contains 4 files: `ax.mxml`, `call_flfunc.html`, `ax.js` and `ax.css`.
You should put the last three files and the generated ax.swf file in the same folder on your web server (or modify their path where they are referenced), and it will work.

**ax.mxml**: your main flex application's structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" 
    width="300" height="300" backgroundColor="#bee3f6"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.controls.Alert;

            public function sayWhat():void {
                Alert.show("Hi");
            }

            public function onCreationComplete():void {
                Security.allowDomain("localhost");

                // binds this.sayWhat to the external interface, so when from   
                // javascript is called the compiled swf object's sayWhat function,
                // it will be transferred to this.sayWhat. 
                ExternalInterface.addCallback("sayWhat", sayWhat);

                // The next line tells the external interface (the parent application:
                // browser window), that this application has finished loading, its 
                // ready to be used.
                // In js there has to be a global method with this name.
                ExternalInterface.call("onFlashAppInited");
            }        

        ]]>             
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

**call_flfunc.html**: the html content into which the ax.swf is embedded

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>AX</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link href="ax.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div id="app-header">
                <input type="button" value="Call Flex function"
                    onclick="onButtonClick()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- tmp is a not displayed div element used just to hold the swf 
            until it gets rendered inside the app div -->
        <div id="tmp">
            <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="ax"
                width="300" height="300"
                codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
                <param name="movie" value="ax.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#bee3f6" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
                <embed src="ax.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#bee3f6" width="300"
                    height="300" name="ax" align="middle" play="true" loop="false"
                    quality="high" allowScriptAccess="always"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                    pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"> </embed>
            </object>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ax.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ax.js**: contains all the necessary javascript classes and functions

```
function Util(){
    this.ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    this.isOpera = this.ua.indexOf("opera") > -1;
    this.isSafari = (/webkit|khtml/).test(this.ua);
    this.isIE = !this.isOpera && this.ua.indexOf("msie") > -1;
    this.isIE7 = !this.isOpera && this.ua.indexOf("msie 7") > -1;
    this.isGecko = !this.isSafari && this.ua.indexOf("gecko") > -1;
    this.ieVersion = parseInt(this.ua.substring(this.ua.indexOf("msie") + 4));
    if (this.ieVersion == 0) {
        this.ieVersion = 100;
    }
}
Util.prototype = {};
var util = new Util();

/**
 * 
 * @param id
 * @param swf
 * @param width
 * @param height
 * @param scriptAccess
 * @param allowFullscreen
 * @return
 */
function FO(id, swf, width, height, scriptAccess, allowFullscreen){
    this.id = id;
    this.movie = swf;
    this.height = height ? height : 180;
    this.width = width ? width : 240;
    this.scriptAccess = scriptAccess ? scriptAccess : "always";
    this.allowFullscr = allowFullscreen ? "true" : "false";
    this.obj = document.createElement("embed");
    this.obj.src = this.movie;
    this.obj.width = this.width;
    this.obj.height = this.height;
    this.obj.name = this.id;
    this.obj.id = this.id;
    this.obj.align = "middle";
    this.obj.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
    this.obj.setAttribute("quality", "high");
    this.obj.setAttribute("bgColor", "#bee3f6");
    this.obj.setAttribute("play", "true");
    this.obj.setAttribute("loop", "false");
    this.obj.setAttribute("allowScriptAccess", this.scriptAccess);
    this.obj.setAttribute("allowFullscreen", this.allowFullscr);
    this.obj.setAttribute("pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer");
}
FO.prototype = {
    id :null,
    width :null,
    height :null,
    movie :null,
    scriptAccess :null,
    allowFullscr :null,
    obj :null,

    addParam : function(name, value){
        var p = document.createElement("param");
        p.name = name;
        p.value = value;
        this.obj.appendChild(p);
    }
};
var app = document.getElementById("app");
var appInited = false;

function onButtonClick(){
    if (appInited)
        flashApp.sayWhat();
    else
        alert("Flash app not inited!");
}

function init(){
    if (util.isIE)
        flashApp = document.getElementById("ax");
    else 
        flashApp = new FO("ax", "ax.swf", 300, 300).obj;
    app.appendChild(flashApp);
}

function onFlashAppInited() {
    // alert("Flash app inited!");
    appInited = true;
    // remove the temporary swf container: tmp
    document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("tmp"));
}
window.onload = init;
```

**ax.css**: the style sheet applied to the `call_flfunc.html` page

```
html, body {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
object, embed {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
#app {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 545px;
    text-align: center;
}
#app-header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1000px !important;
    text-align: center;
    height: 23px;
    line-height: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
#tmp {
    display: none;
    visible: false;
}
```

I hope it's understandable, and you can work from it.

Comment: To see this app running, check [this link](http://tordai.rekaszeru.ro/ax/ax.html). The source is downloadable as well.

Comment: @rekaszeru: I see the alert as Flash App not inited even in your link.Any reasons for this..

Comment: i forgot to add the Security.allowDomain(my.domain.spec) in mxml, it could be one reason. and might be the flash player version. i work with 10.1 currently. I've updated the sample, if it was a security error, it must be gone now. If you adopt the sources and try them out on localhost, it should work though.

Comment: This is really odd. I've uploaded it to three other servers (not locals), accessed through a number of proxies, and it is working fine. :-? Maybe you have some restrictions? Can you debug your client side (js), to see what is happening there (e.g. firebug)? What is the color of the box you see on the page? if it is red, the swf is not loaded. but if it's blue, it is loaded and must respond to the click. what kind of browser are you using?

Comment: do you have a sample or clear use case, because i'm afraid can't understand this question. Basically, the width and height attributes you set in your Application tag should be used in your html as well (in px), and used in the js too (when instantiating the FO class).

Answer (score 1):

You might need an other kind of workaround in js to call the flash function from any browser.

Here i share my way to accomplish this (hope it is not deprecated yet...). You need a javascript class (i named it FO):

```
/**
 * 
 * @param id
 * @param swf
 * @param width
 * @param height
 * @param scriptAccess
 * @param allowFullscreen
 * @return
 */
function FO(id, swf, width, height, scriptAccess, allowFullscreen){
    this.id = id;
    this.movie = swf;
    this.height = height ? height : 180;
    this.width = width ? width : 240;
    this.scriptAccess = scriptAccess ? scriptAccess : "always";
    this.allowFullscr = allowFullscreen ? "true" : "false";
    this.obj = document.createElement("embed");
    this.obj.src = this.movie;
    this.obj.width = this.width;
    this.obj.height = this.height;
    this.obj.name = this.id;
    this.obj.id = this.id;
    this.obj.align = "middle";
    this.obj.type = "application/x-shockwave-flash";
    this.obj.setAttribute("quality", "high");
    this.obj.setAttribute("bgColor", "#bee3f6");
    this.obj.setAttribute("play", "true");
    this.obj.setAttribute("loop", "false");
    this.obj.setAttribute("allowScriptAccess", this.scriptAccess);
    this.obj.setAttribute("allowFullscreen", this.allowFullscr);
    this.obj.setAttribute("pluginspage", "http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer");
}
FO.prototype = {
    id :null,
    width :null,
    height :null,
    movie :null,
    scriptAccess :null,
    allowFullscr :null,
    obj :null,

    addParam : function(name, value){
        var p = document.createElement("param");
        p.name = name;
        p.value = value;
        this.obj.appendChild(p);
    }
};
```

You will need an initialization method (or extend the existing one):

```
// should be called on window.onload
function init() {
    var flashObject = null;
    if (isIE)
        flashObject = document.getElementById("myMovieName");
    else 
    {
        flashObject = new FO("myMovieName", "ax.swf", 225, 200).obj;
        // **app** is the id of a div / html container element, 
        // in which your <object> is positioned. 
        document.getElementById("app").appendChild(flashObject);
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

and for calling the desired method:

```
//somewhere else in your code:
if (flashObject)
    flashObject.sayWhat();
```

Comment: @rekaszeru:Actually there seems to be some error with the flash code.IE clearly says this..Can u please look at it..

Comment: What is the IE error exactly? Did you set the `Security.allowDomain("*.yourdomain.com");' and/or the `Security.allowDomain("localhost");` in flash before adding the callback? Can you maybe temporarily share a link with your running application, so that i can check it directly? thanks!

Comment: Can u let me know where to post the temporary link..Is there any place that i can do this..I have set the parameters `Security.allowDomain("*.yourdomain.com");' Security.allowDomain("localhost");`

Comment: you can edit your question and paste it there, and if you don't want others to see it, then after a few minutes you just remove it.

Comment: Hi Naveen, please see my new post, it has all the necessary sources you might need. I've tested it on 5 browsers, and works. Let me know if you need further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When calling from javascript try:

```
myMovieName.sayWhat();
```

Comment: Error: myMovieName.sayWhat is not a function

Comment: Oh, move the External.addCallback("sayWhat", sayWhat) out of your initCamera function. If that doesn't help i'm afraid i'm out of ideas.